# Not able to access key-values pairs in a JSON using Play library in scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using elasticsearch where as a response from the server I get a JSON.
So,

```
val builder = new TermVectorRequestBuilder(client, "new_index", "documents", "0056").setSelectedFields("text")
builder.setTermStatistics(true).setFieldStatistics(true)
val resp: TermVectorResponse = builder.execute().actionGet()
val json_reader = XContentFactory.contentBuilder(XContentType.JSON).prettyPrint()
```

where `json_reader` is of type `org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder`.

Following is what `json_reader` looks like:

```
"_index""new_index",
"_type" "documents",
"_id" "0056",
"_version" 1,
"found" true,
"took" 2,
"term_vectors" {
  "text" : {
    "field_statistics" : {
      "sum_doc_freq" : 26433,
      "doc_count" : 15,
      "sum_ttf" : 29089
    },
    "terms" : {
      "11" : {
        "doc_freq" : 4,
        "ttf" : 5,
        "term_freq" : 1,
        "tokens" : [ {
          "position" : 306,
          "start_offset" : 1791,
          "end_offset" : 1793
        } ]
      },
      "11 30" : {
        "doc_freq" : 1,
        "ttf" : 1,
        "term_freq" : 1,
        "tokens" : [ {
          "position" : 306,
          "start_offset" : 1791,
          "end_offset" : 1796
        } ]
      },
      "11 30 p.m" : {
        "doc_freq" : 1,
        "ttf" : 1,
        "term_freq" : 1,
        "tokens" : [ {
          "position" : 306,
          "start_offset" : 1791,
          "end_offset" : 1800
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I convert it to a string and pass it to `Play's` JSON Parser

```
val termVec = json_reader.string()
val json = Json.parse(termVec)
```

Since I am using `play 2.3.8`, so I referred [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/ScalaJson) documentation. As per the documentation, in order to traverse a JsValue structure. But `parse` converts to `JsonNode` type. None of the examples given in the documentation are working.

So doing `val indexName = json \ "_index"` results in error

```
Error:(82, 26) value \ is not a member of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
    val indexName = json \ "_index"
                         ^
```

How should I use `play` so that able to get key-value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play has APIs for both Java and Scala.
You're using the Java api.

You want to use (Scala):
`import play.api.libs.json._`

And *not* (Java):
`import play.libs._`

Try this:

```
val json: JsValue = play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(termVec)
val indexName = json \ "_index"
```

Answer (score -2):

Check the import makes sure that you have this:

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
```